# When referencing a private variable, do you need the this.variableName declaration?

Tags: java, variables, constructor, return, private

```
public class sample {
    private int x = 3;
    public sample() {}
    public sample(int num) {
        this();
        x = num;
    }

    public int getX() {
        // should I use return this.x; or just return x;? Does it matter which one?
    }
}
```

I've used the return x; style in my code until now, and I was wondering if using return this.x; provided any benefits, or if it was purely for readability/clarity. My Apologies if this seems vague or confusing, I don't really know how else to word it.

Comment: why don't you try?  Also why do you call `this();`?

Comment: I had some stuff in the preset class that i didn't include in the code snippet because it wasn't really relevant. And I have always just done it the way where it just does `return x;`, but have noticed many people do the this.x instead, and wondered if there was any benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `setX(int x)`, in order to disambiguate between the parameter `x` and the field `x` you would need to write something like

```
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Otherwise (if the `x` is not [*shadowed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)), then you don't need to specify `this` (it is *implicit*).

```
public int getX() {
    return x; // <-- same as return this.x;
}
```

Comment: Is it common for people to use a local variable with the same name as a private variable, or is this something that is generally avoided?

Comment: @JavaTheHutt I would say it's not uncommon with mutators; but then it's also not uncommon to see style guides recommend that you *always* use `this.x` when accessing a field.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should just be able to use `return x;`. The only reason why you should technically use `this.x` is if you had a local variable `x` in the method.